# Sonatype Nexus: How to use my Seagate personal cloud storage device as a repository for my maven artifacts?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, artifactory, sonatype

I'm currently running Sonatype nexus in my personal laptop as a Windows service. All my maven artifacts are stored in my personal computer hard disk space.

Due to heavy load on my machine (4GB RAM and 512GB hard disk), I'm unable to work seamlessly. If anyone had a experience in setting up  personal cloud storage device as repo for maven artifacts, Please help me by sharing your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So, since you added `[artifactory]` tag to your question, here's an [Artifactory Online service](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/versions/#Cloud), which provides you with exactly what you are looking for, except it's not Nexus, but Artifactory.

If you prefer using IaaS and not SaaS, you can [run Artifactory on AWS, Azure or Google Cloud Platform with Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/artifactory).

And if you are wondering what are the differences between Artifactory and Nexus, [this comparison](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix) can be helpful.